# Accessing JSON response

Tags: json

I am storing the response of a REST Get request and trying to access as below,

```
final JSONObject receivedItem =  new   JSONObject(response.readEntity(String.class));
```

This is the sample response,

```
[
    {
        "timeStamp": 1511136000000,
        "contextKeys": [
            {
                "tKey": "Test1",
                "contextKey": "Location",
                "contextValue": "San Jose",
                "eCount": 3
            },
            {
                "tKey": "Test1",
                "contextKey": "Name",
                "contextValue": "User1",
                "eCount": 3
            } 
     }
]
```

And i am getting the below error,

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:496)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:180)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:403)
```

Any clues ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is with storing and accessing json response try this response instead;

I am presuming that you are using javascript; Anyways, core idea is the same;

```
var jsonStorage;
$.getJSON('your url',(json) => {
    jsonStorage = json;
});

console.log(jsonStorage) //your jsonresponse is now available here;
```

Comment: That was a type with copy paste Rajkumar.Even with valid json i am receiving that error.

Comment: @SHG Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Rajkumar pointed out, in your example there is a missing close bracket - but this may just be a simple typing error.

The actual error message is saying `A JSONObject text must begin with '{'` which is because JSON objects are exactly that, objects. You need to use a JSONArray to parse your example JSON as follows:

`final JSONArray receivedItem = new JSONArray(response.readEntity(String.class));`

This may change some of your other code to handle this as an array vs an object.